# Find the occurrences of unique element in list in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

For finding occurrences of unique element in a list in python i used

```
import collections

a='77888'
b=list(collections.Counter(a).items())
```

but the b is sorted in order of occurences `b=[('8',3),('7',2)]`. But is want unsorted `b`. How can i achieve this?

Comment: No, `b` is **not** sorted. The order is arbitrary. Any sorting you think took place is a coincidence here. And the second value is a *number*, not a string; the output is `[('8', 3), ('7', 2)]`.

Comment: Why do you feel you need to list the `Counter()` contents in arbitrary order to find occurrences of unique elements?

Comment: I do not want arbitrary order. I want output as `b=[('7',2),('8',3)]` in the order of appearance

Comment: You are trying to find unique elements; can you give examples of input and what you wanted to find in those? Your sample doesn't have unique elements, to begin with. This sounds like you are chasing Y, but the real problem is X, see [What is the XY problem?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find unique items in the list `a`:

```
from collections import Counter

unique_items = [item for item, count in Counter(a).items() if count == 1]
```

If input is sorted then you could use `itertools.groupby()`:

```
from itertools import groupby

unique_items = [key for key, group in groupby(a) if len(list(group)) == 1]
```

If you want to get items and their frequencies in the same order as in the input, you could define `OrderedCounter`:

```
from collections import Counter, OrderedDict

class OrderedCounter(Counter, OrderedDict):
    pass
```

then:

```
>>> list(OrderedCounter('77888').items())
[('7', 2), ('8', 3)]
>>> list(OrderedCounter('88877').items())
[('8', 3), ('7', 2)]
```